# Suppress message box for infragistics trial version

Tags: c#, infragistics

I installed infragistics trial version. While each time running the application through Visual Studio 2008, I'm getting the message box like "this is a trial version".

I just want to suppress this message. How can i do this?

Comment: Just i want to see the infragistics controls, bypass is not the intension, This message box is annoying. This Message box is keep on coming on every run (hitting F5). Even i don'n know how this control is helping, how can buy this?

Answer (score 4):

You can buy Infragistics.

This error box is just to warn you that you are running on a trial and that your license (trial license) will expire.

Answer (score 4):

Your probably in the wrong place if your asking how to bypass a system put in place to get people to buy software.

As Snake said, if you want to use the product without holdups, buy it, otherwise be greatful you are able to run a trial mode :)

Comment: Just i want to see the infragistics controls, bypass is not the intension, This message box is annoying. This Message box is keep on coming on every run (hitting F5). Even i don'n know how this control is helping, how can buy this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand.  I found the constant interruption annoying, like a PHB interrupting every 2 minutes for a status report.  Did Infragistics think I was so stupid that I'd forgotten their stuff was running in trial mode when I had already dismissed the popup three times in this minute?  Has anyone at Infragistics ever trialed their package as someone might who is considering if it can be included in a current project -- Change one property, run, change another, run, change another, run, ... ??  Apparently not.  The process is - Change one property, run, DismissDlgBox, change another, run, DismissDlgBox, change another, run, DismissDlgBox ...

Long before finishing figuring out whether Infragistics could help in my project I had enough of a company I perceived as assuming I'm an idiot and thought nothing of wasting my time.  I deinstalled and moved on.  For me, the popup on every run was part of their anti-sales strategy.

Comment: Yes, you understood my problem, i think its time to uninstall Infragistics. It's stupidity.